# Running a video from test case in android

Tags: android

I am running a test case using AndroidTestCase class in eclipse. I want to run a video through this test case .

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {

            file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.v("tarun", file.getPath());
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(),
                    Uri.parse(file.getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/arun.mp4"));
            mediaPlayer.setAIAContext(false);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } 
catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Failed due to I/O exception");
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();

 Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Now when the test case runs only sound is coming no video is displayed, but I want to show a video here for a specified time. I just know that I need a videoview here but I am not able to implement it. So please give me some direction here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have my Video been played successfully.

I suggest you for the following Code wherein i am running my application successfully

The Code is as Follows:

**XML file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVideoGallery"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/gallery" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnVideoGallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/below_this_text_video_will_be_displayed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vvDisplayVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java File:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnVideoGallery,btnCancel;
    private VideoView vvDisplayVideo;
    /** The Constant PICK_VIDEO. */
    private static final int PICK_VIDEO=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_options);

        btnVideoGallery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVideoGallery);
        vvDisplayVideo=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vvDisplayVideo);
        btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        vvDisplayVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnVideoGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent video=new Intent();
                video.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                video.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(video, PICK_VIDEO);

            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent goStartUp=new Intent(VideoActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
                goStartUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(goStartUp);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_VIDEO) {

            vvDisplayVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vvDisplayVideo.setVideoURI(data.getData());
            vvDisplayVideo.setFocusable(true);
            MediaController mc=new MediaController(this);
            vvDisplayVideo.setMediaController(mc);
            Log.i("True", "Executed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent goStartUp=new Intent(VideoActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
        goStartUp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(goStartUp);
        finish();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Also you can modify the Manifest File as per your use:

```
<manifest ...
<uses-sdk...  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

<application .....
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Actually I want to send intent from a AndroidTestCase class and Intent constructor is not defined for AndroidTestCase, and above code is simply a code for playing video. Could you elaborate more?